# update URL string with different port

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

In my program I got URL like following format,
when I use the url.parse nothing happen,I need to change the port ,how it suggested do do that ?

The port is after the colon %3 55123 and I need to change it to 8080

```
  http%3A%2F%2Fmo-de73.mo.bmw.corp%3A55123%2Flogin%2Fcallback&client_id=s2.app
```

The number can be change(any valid port) so I cannot use the replace

Btw there is parser which change the format from %3 to colon and and %2F to slash as standard URL output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you can parse it, you must decode it. You can do this using the built-in `decodeURIComponent` function.

```
var url = require('url');

var encodedUrl = 'http%3A%2F%2Fmo-de73.mo.bmw.corp%3A55123%2Flogin%2Fcallback&client_id=s2.app';

var decodedUrl = decodeURIComponent(encodedUrl);
//=> 'http://mo-de73.mo.bmw.corp:55123/login/callback&client_id=s2.app'

var parts = url.parse(decodedUrl);
/* =>
  { protocol: 'http:',
    slashes: true,
    auth: null,
    host: 'mo-de73.mo.bmw.corp:55123',
    port: '55123',
    hostname: 'mo-de73.mo.bmw.corp',
    hash: null,
    search: null,
    query: null,
    pathname: '/login/callback&client_id=s2.app',
    path: '/login/callback&client_id=s2.app',
    href: 'http://mo-de73.mo.bmw.corp:55123/login/callback&client_id=s2.app' }
*/

parts.port = 8080;
//=> 8080

delete parts.host;
//=> true

url.format(parts);
//=> 'http://mo-de73.mo.bmw.corp:8080/login/callback&client_id=s2.app'
```

The last part there is a bit of a hack. After you update the `port`, your `parts` object will look like this

```
{
  // ...
  host: 'mo-de73.mo.bmw.corp:55123',
  port: '8080',
  hostname: 'mo-de73.mo.bmw.corp',
  // ...
}
```

The `hostname` is correct, but the `host` still has the port hard-coded in there. If you just remove the host using `delete parts.host`, `url.format` will automatically create the correct host using `{hostname}:{port}`.

Maybe there's a better way to do it, but at least this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks a lot 1+ can you please provide example how can I update the port?

Comment: Thanks a lot,last question after I update the port I want the URL again (with the updated port) how can I do that ?

Comment: The port was chaged just in the object parts.port ,I need somehow to get the updated URL with the new port,there is a way to do that?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var url="http%3A%2F%2Fmo-de73.mo.bmw.corp%3A55123%2Flogin%2Fcallback&client_id=s2.app";
url=url.replace('%3A55123',":8080");
var decodedUrl = decodeURIComponent(url);
//decodedUrl=http://mo-de73.mo.bmw.corp:8080/login/callback&client_id=s2.app
```